# Book [Algebraic Topology: An Intuitive Approach] error on n-dimensional ball?

Tags: general-topology

So I was looking at this book and was confused with how the book defines a n-dimensional ball.

"For a natural number n $\geq $ 1, we define the n-dimesional ball (or n-ball) D$^{n}$ by

D$^{n}$ = { (x$_{1}$, x$_{2}$,... x$_{n}$) $\in$ R$^{2}$ | $\sum_{i}$ x$_{i}$$^{2}$ $\leq$ 1 }"

At first I thought that each element had to be an ordered paired, but then I dismissed that for the 1-ball and 3-ball. I checked the James R. Munkres book for another interpretation and found his to be much better. So, does the Sato book have a typo?

B$^n$ = {x | ||x|| $\leq$ 1 }

Comment: $R^2$ should be $R^n$. Otherwise it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Probably $(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

By the way $|x| = \sum_{i}x_i^2$ as a definition, so I don't see any difference!